# BigQuery syntax error with SUM CASE END OVER PARTITION

Tags: google-bigquery

I have this query in BigQuery

```sql
SELECT
        *,
        SUM(CASE 
          WHEN chat_start - prev_chat_end > INTERVAL '10 minutes' OR prev_chat_end IS NULL
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0
        END
        )
        OVER (PARTITION BY agent_id, case_id ORDER BY chat_start) 
            AS assigned_chat_id
    FROM ranked_events
```

What I'm trying to do is to group all the events together if they happen within a 10 minute window of the previous one.

I've tried wrapping the conditions inside the CASE WHEN but I keep getting syntax error that the ')' or the THEN is unexpected.

```sql
SUM(CASE 
          WHEN (chat_start - prev_chat_end > INTERVAL '10 minutes') OR (prev_chat_end IS NULL)
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0
        END

SUM(CASE 
          WHEN ((chat_start - prev_chat_end > INTERVAL '10 minutes') OR (prev_chat_end IS NULL))
          THEN 1 
          ELSE 0
        END
```